# Generate dockerfile from specific container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a running container which I do not have the docker run command nor the dockerfile for.

My goal is to edit this container and add some labels to it.

The first step (I think) is to generate a dockerfile based on the specific running container. This way I can edit the dockerfile and recreate the image as a new container.

Please note that I am not trying to recreate the generic image from the the container is made from. I am trying to recreate the specific container and it's specific settings.

How can this be done ?

Comment: `docker history <image_id>`?

Comment: Thats for the image and not the container.